# Django: Search many to many field while creating object

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin, django-2.0

I've got a use case where I have multiple `Ingredient` that can be linked to a `Recipe` through the Django admin. Now I have around a hundred ingredients which makes it very difficult to select the ingredients in the following UI.

[image]

Is there a way to add a search field or something similar to the django admin for easier selection?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have few choices.

#### 1. `filter_horizontal`

With filter_horizontal, you can use horizontal m2m ui in admin. I prefer this way using m2m in admin.

```
class YourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('m2m_field',)
    ...
```

And the result will be...

[image]

#### 2. `raw_id_fields` [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields)

You can use `raw_id_fields` for using pop-up modal with your m2m fields.

It's bit useful when you have lots of m2m field. Also, it's easy to filter which m2m obj to add.

```
class YourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fiedls = ('m2m_field',)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to filter over ingredients and select it one by one on admin UI

> You can use django forms builtin [**`CheckboxSelectMultiple`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
>   widget in place of `SelectMultiple` to make selection easy

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin

class RecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta(object):
        model = Recipe
        widgets = {
            'Ingredient': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        }


class RecipeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = RecipeForm

admin.site.register(Recipe, RecipeAdmin)
```

---

> Alternatively, you can use [**`django-better-filter-widget`**](https://github.com/ExoticObjects/django-better-filter-widget)
>   package if you want a search input on choices, Refer Github repo for
>   installation

It is a custom widget, created by overriding `SelectMultiple` widget of 
 django forms

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from better_filter_widget import BetterFilterWidget

class RecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta(object):
        model = Recipe
        widgets = {
            'Ingredient': BetterFilterWidget(),
        }


class RecipeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = RecipeForm

admin.site.register(Recipe, RecipeAdmin)
```

Comment: Can `BetterFilterWidget` be used in a 'normal' form, out of the admin?