# Django ModelForm: search filter many to many field widget

Tags: django, django-forms, widget

I'm working with this model:

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    id_sample = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)
    sample_id_sex = models.ForeignKey(Sex, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='id_sex', verbose_name='Sexe')
    pools = models.ManyToManyField(Pool, through='SamplePoolIndexCand', through_fields=('sample_id', 'pool_id'), blank=True, verbose_name="Pools")
```

`pools` is a `m2m` field from this model:

```
class Pool(models.Model):
    id_pool = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50, verbose_name="Pool")
    samples = models.ManyToManyField('Sample', through='SamplePoolIndexCand', blank=True, verbose_name="Mostres")
```

I created this `ModelForm`:

```
class FormulariMostra(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = ("name", "sample_id_sex", "pools",)
```

It works fine but the problem is that the `pools` field can contain thousands of values. A similar question was asked here: [Django: Search many to many field while creating object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51279020/django-search-many-to-many-field-while-creating-object)

I tried this widget recommended there https://github.com/ExoticObjects/django-better-filter-widget but it seems outdated...

Is there any alternative? I know this can be done in the admin but I want to do it in the `ModelForm`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are `autocomplete_fields` for that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields

So you can write:

```
class FormulariMostra(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        autocomplete_fields = ["pools"]
        fields = ("name", "sample_id_sex", "pools",)
```

or there is also `raw_id_fields`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields

Comment: But this can be used outside the admin?

Comment: Oo, if you are using Django templates then this thing https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/ is pretty great.

Comment: I tried but I couldn't make it work... I found this one https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects but I have problems to implement the add button.